# Memory management of Counter data structure in Python

Tags: python

In `python`, we have a very helpful data structure called `Counter` under the `collections` library. Basically we know that `Counter` store the data passed to it in an unordered dictionary manner.

Namely,

```
counter = Counter("xxyz")
```

would give

```
Counter({'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 1})
```

If I do, `c['x']`, I get `2`.

When I do, `c[0]`, I get `0`.

If I do, `c['1']`, I get `0`.

If I do, `c['999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990']`, I get `0`.

So, I was wondering,

1. How `Counter` initialize its memory?
2. How it allocates memory?

For example, I did not assign any value for the index `999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990`,

but when I'm trying to access `c['999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990']` I'm getting `0`. Obviously it means, the `Counter` initializes everything with a default `0` value.

So how is the memory allocation is happening behind the scene?

Comment: It's just if `c[k]` exists then return val else return 0

Comment: Which implementation are you asking about?

Comment: @Wood the implementation of `Counter`..

Comment: @OsmanMamun so you mean, `Counter` internally maintains something like a `Dictionary`?

Comment: yes, it's inherited its behavior from dictionary and should have a get or __getitem__ method that will return val if key exists else return 0

Comment: `https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/collections.py` see this code for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter is nothing but a dict subclass; it works like a regular dict with some helpers

You can see its implementation here [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/**init**.py#L505](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L505)

You are interested in how `c['999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999990']` works; so, it works using `__missing__` method, which defines how the dict works when the key is not in the dict keys; `Counter` does not initializes anything with 0, it just returns 0 by default.

```
    def __missing__(self, key):
        'The count of elements not in the Counter is zero.'
        # Needed so that self[missing_item] does not raise KeyError
        return 0
```